# Scheme: The purpose of procedure arguments in SICP: 1.3 (Higher Order Procedures)

Tags: scheme, racket, sicp

In section 1.3 of SICP, we are abstracting the summation process by introducing two procedures as arguments for the procedure.

```
(define (sum term a next b)
   (if (> a b) 0
       (+ (term a) (sum term (next a) next b))))
```

Why can't we write the same procedure like this:

```
(define (identity a ) a)
(define (next a) (+ a 1)
(define (sum a b)
   (if (> a b) 0
       (+ (identity a) (sum (next a) b))))
```

I am not able to understand the reason for **passing procedures as arguments** in this particular example.

Is there any special reason for that? Or is it just for the purpose of demonstrating the concept?

Is there a better example?

Comment: we can; we just lose the flexibility since we fix the definitions if we write it the second way. so we can calculate anything we could with the first choice, but -- we can't do two different choices at once, because for each choice we need to re-write the two global functions, `term` and `next`. but with the first way we can just use two different pairs of temporarily-defined lambda functions.

Comment: That was the confusion I had.  Why not make `term` and `next` global. But the below answers justify the first version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for passing procedures as arguments is that in this way you can *parameterize* your procedure, changing its behavior. Surely, in the original version you can simply add all the numbers, the same as in the second version:

```
(define (sum term a next b)
  (if (> a b)
      0
      (+ (term a) (sum term (next a) next b))))

(define (identity a) a)
(define (plus1 a) (+ 1 a))
(sum identity 1 plus1 10)
=> 55
```

But now you also have the flexibility to calculate other series, without changing the original code - you just have to pass different procedures to get different results. Say, you want to calculate the sum of the squares:

```
(define (square a) (* a a))
(sum square 1 plus1 10)
=> 385
```

Or you want to calculate the sum, but skipping numbers:

```
(define (plus2 a) (+ 2 a))
(sum identity 1 plus2 10)
=> 25
```

That is the power of higher order procedures: customizability and extensibility with no changes to the base code. And because procedures can be written in such a way that they're composable and reusable, you have a very flexible way to think about computation, without having to write boilerplate code over and over again.

Comment: Yes. I guess the power of abstraction comes when we are actually dealing with lists. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, but you can think of the `sum` procedure as lazily generating a list, where only the current element is considered, and the result is accumulated.

Comment: Can I consider **parameterize procedures** a kind of **polymorphism**?

Comment: Higher order functions and polymorphism are related but orthogonal concepts. See a discussion here: https://www.cs.princeton.edu/~dpw/courses/cos326-12/notes/polymorphism.php

Comment: Thanks.  I have already read it but couldn't make out much.

Answer (score 2):

It just like you say it just **summation notation**.
If you learn basic math you might need to calculate many **series**.

- 1+2+3+...+n
- 1/n+2/n+3/n+...+n/n
- 0+2+3+...+n
- 1^2+2^+3^2+...+n^2
- f(1)+f(2)+f(3)+...+f(n)
- f(1)+f(3)+f(5)+...

We can think in many point.

- abstract : it basic abstract. Summation notation we all learn this in math course. So not strange.
- modification: In your second version you have to rewrite all code. In first verstion no need. See demo below.
- understand : If people see code like this: `(define (1/1+1/2+1/3+...+1/k k) (summation / 1 add1 k))` Then we only need to translate to sum of 1/i form i=1 to i=k (in here is i≦k) just like we learn it in math course.
- easily test
- extension : Maybe someday you want extension to vector series.
  If we want to add vector series: vector-1 + vector-2 + ... + vector-n
  We only need to change this `+` function (inside `sum`) to `add-vector`
  and add `if-else` to check input is number or vector. We can design something like `my-inf` so we can use another way to calculate `1+2+3+...+inf`.
- new algorithm or speedup : If we talk about `sqrt` we all agree this abstraction is important because we have many algorithm to calculate `sqrt`.

```
#lang racket
(define (sum term a next b)
   (if (> a b) 0
       (+ (term a) (sum term (next a) next b))))

(define (1+2+...+k k)
  (sum identity 1 add1 k))

(define (0^2+1^2+2^2+...+k^2 k)
  (sum sqr 0 add1 k))

(define (1+3+5+...+k k)
  (sum (λ (n) (- (* 2 n) 1)) 1 add1 k))

(define (1/1+1/2+1/3+...+1/k k)
  (sum / 1 add1 k))

(define (1/1^2+1/2^2+1/3^2+...+1/k^2 k)
  (sum (λ (n) (/ (sqr n))) 1 add1 k))

; sqr(0)+sqr(2)+sqr(4)+sqr(6)
(sum sqr 0 (λ (a) (+ a 2)) 7) ; 56

;;; TEST
(0^2+1^2+2^2+...+k^2 3) ; 14
(1+2+...+k 100) ; 5050
(1+3+5+...+k 5) ; 1+3+5+7+9=25
(1/1+1/2+1/3+...+1/k 5) ; (+ 1/1 1/2 1/3 1/4 1/5) = 2 + 17/60
(1/1^2+1/2^2+1/3^2+...+1/k^2 3) ; (+ 1 1/4 1/9) = 1 + 13/36
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to compute

f(a0) + f(a0+r) + f(a0+2r) + ...

you cannot use your second form but use the form from SICP.  Scheme helps you implementing in a nice way the abstract concept of [∑](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation).